# Calculations on formatted text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that will collect various data about properties.  The user enters in values to select fields and onBlur, those values are formatted with comma's, dollar signs, and/or percentage signs.

I'm trying to create some real time calculations based on those inputs, but I'm having a hard time getting started on this.  I have created a jfiddle page and have been playing around with ideas for the past few hours, but I just cannot seem to get the first calculation working.

I know I need to strip out any characters and have tried parseInt, parseFloat, replace, ect.  Just nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance.

```
function formatNumber(number, digits, decimalPlaces, withCommas)
{
number       = number.toString();   
var simpleNumber = '';

// Strips out the dollar sign and commas.
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; ++i)
{
    if ("0123456789.".indexOf(number.charAt(i)) >= 0)
        simpleNumber += number.charAt(i);
}

number = parseFloat(simpleNumber);

if (isNaN(number))      number     = 0;
if (withCommas == null) withCommas = false;
if (digits     == 0)    digits     = 1;

var integerPart = (decimalPlaces > 0 ? Math.floor(number) : 
Math.round(number));
var string      = "";

for (var i = 0; i < digits || integerPart > 0; ++i)
{
    // Insert a comma every three digits.
    if (withCommas && string.match(/^\d\d\d/))
        string = "," + string;

    string      = (integerPart % 10) + string;
    integerPart = Math.floor(integerPart / 10);
}

if (decimalPlaces > 0)
{
    number -= Math.floor(number);
    number *= Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);

    string += "." + formatNumber(number, decimalPlaces, 0);
}

return string;
}
function sumCalc() {          // function to remove comma and then calculate

     var glasf = 
document.getElementById('gross_land_sf').value.replace(/,/g, "");
     document.getElementById('gross_land_acre').value = formatNumber(glasf/43560);       
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vva3x3wu/4/

Comment: not sure what you mean by first calculation? can you clarify?

Comment: As you can see, there will be a series of calculations, but, for now, I'm just trying to get one to work, (the first calculation located at the bottom of the code).  From there, I'm sure I can figure out the rest, hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ? I did some fixes:

> https://jsfiddle.net/vva3x3wu/11/

In the link you put in the comment you removed class `.cal` from the first input, so calculations will not star until you tab from the last input.

Comment: I added the code to jfiddle, and the calculations come back NaN,  (that's more than what was happening earlier, so progress!).

https://jsfiddle.net/vva3x3wu/9/

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm looking for.  And thank you also for pointing out my removal of the calc class.